# How to get a string that is contained on an array using LinQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I need to get the string of an array that contains "xxxx.html" using LinQ.

I have this:

```
filePaths.Any(s => s.Contains("xxxx.html")
```

And I recieve true if it contains that string. Now I need to get the string that contains "xxxx.html" but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

I'm a noob using linq.

Comment: Did you look at the various LINQ functions? Try `First()` or `Where()`.

Comment: Also a note that using Contains() will match anything with that as a substring.  For example, "yyyxxxx.htmlfoo" would match.  This may or may not be an issue in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` (returns null if not found)

```
filePaths.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("xxxx.html"))
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried?

```
var result = filePaths.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("xxxx.html"));
```

Comment: This works well at returning one item or `NULL` if the string is not found. Presumably this is what OP is looking for. However, you can substitute `FirstOrDefault()` for `Where()` if you want an IEnumerable<T> collection of ALL items containing the string.

Comment: I didnt' use the Where, because if he doesn't know.. it will return IQueryable when not assigned or executed.. but is perfectly legal to do so. thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want more than the first item in the array with the desired value, you could also use:

```
filePaths.Where(s => s.Contains("xxxx.html");
```

Will return an Enumerable with all items matching the condition.